# How did people tune their instruments in the past?

Tags: tuning, history

Today we are using electronic tuners and know everything about frequencies but in the past, like before the 16th century, how could people tune their instruments? Did they tune them to specific frequencies? What reference did they have? Did they use some kind of instrument?

Comment: Note that many musicians still tune by ear today. It's arguably better than what you get with an electronic tuner, certainly on instruments that aren't really equal-tempered.

Comment: I tune with the ear too but usually I need a reference to  find the 'real' E for example. If I don't have a reference, every string is tuned perfectly relatively to each other but when I try to jam with a backing track for example I might be completely out of tune.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Never mind the 16th C., even in the 1960s, reference points were not considered necessary by some recording bands, particularly those with only guitars and basses to go with drums! As long as one of the guitars was in tune with itself, the others used that as a datum point.

Back in the 16th C., there was not a great deal of travel involved with musicians; making music was parochial, so the need for an industry standard such as we rely on nowadays wasn't needed. With easily tuneable (?!) instruments, i.e. lutes, as long as they were in tune with other no-so-easily tuneable instruments, it wasn't really an issue. And tuning was such that some instruments sounded better in one key (no 12EDO yet).

Tuning forks, as already mentioned, were around from the beginning of the 1700s, so there was no 'official' datum point anyway at a time previous.

Back in the '60s, I used to drop a house key on a hard surface, which gave me a reference to keep my guitar in tune, and I guess similar ideas were used by instrumentalists who were fastidious enough to keep their instruments on pitch.

So, basically, everyone would, as previously said, tune to whatever instrument sounded right, but was the most difficult to alter anyway,.

Comment: I once saw a guitarist pull out a set of pitch pipes & blow an E. Everybody else just stared at him as though he'd suggested they all play naked that night.

Comment: @Tetsujin - nearly 60 yrs ago, I had pitchpipes with my first guitar. They were not in tune...

Comment: I wish comments would simply let me type 'LOL'

Comment: @Tetsujin - LOL

Comment: I'm a rock and pop musician, so I don't know much about those things, but isn't that pretty much how orchestras still tune even today? Pick the instrument which is hardest/impossible to tune as the reference, then the first violin tunes to that, and all others to the first violin. I actually read an article a couple of years ago complaining about the miserable quality of most electronic tuners which advocated this even for rock bands: tune the bass to the "best" available tuning reference, record the bass track, then have the rest tune to the playback.

Comment: @JörgWMittag - as a bass player, amongst other things, I tend to leave my final tuning till everyone else is happy. I wouldn't want them tuning to me - the bass notes are sufficiently low enough to be out slightly, and not many would notice. In orchestras, the oboe is used as reference, partly as it's piercing, partly because it can be tuned, but it's best left (my words). A question exists here about that. Of course, if a piano or organ is involved, it should be at concert pitch, but in any case, everyone tunes to it. Even, maybe, the oboe!

Comment: @Tim: Thanks for that insight! IIRC, the argument in that article was that strings vary slightly in pitch depending on how hard they are played, and that effect is more pronounced on thicker strings, therefore in a typical rock band, the bass is the instrument most affected by this. Since it is unlikely that the bass player will play exactly as hard when tuning as he will when recording, the suggestion was to tune the bass as good as possible, but then tune the rest of the instrument to the *playback of the recorded bass track*; in fact, for songs that have heavier and quieter parts, it even …

Comment: … suggests recording the parts separately and have the other instruments tune to the bass *as it is playing the part you are about to record*. Honestly, I found the entire article a bit over the top, but that's at least one studio that suggests this approach. The article also suggests that the entire band should all use one single tuner, since even tuners from the same manufacturer apparently can be out of tune with each other … or so the article claims.

Comment: @Tetsujin  didn't I see the bass player for Red hot Chili Peppers do just that?

Answer (score 6):

In the case of the lute, a common practice was apparently to "tune the treble string as high as it will go without breaking, then tune the remaining strings in accordance with the first." ([source](http://www.ronnmcfarlane.com/a-brief-history-of-the-lute)).  This of course depends on the diameter of the string, the construction of the (gut) string and the size of the lute.  Lutes were made in fairly well standardized sizes ([source](http://luteshop.co.uk/articles/historical-pitch/)), which suggests that the instruments were not necessarily tuned to any reference pitch, but just so the top string (on which a lot of the melody is played) sounds good and the rest of the strings tuned to match (in some particular temperament).  Presumably a group of players would tune according to the top string of all the instruments that was closes to breaking? [caveat: I am not an expert on this topic!]

ETA: Lute players (especially baroque lute) spend half their lives tuning their lute, and the other half playing out of tune ;o)

Comment: Must have been a good market for top strings for the lute.I did the same with rulers at school, but they just broke before we knew how far they'd bend!

Comment: Indeed, I have nylon top strings on most of my lutes (I have a gut string on my 7 course lute, but they don't last long!)  Perhaps that is why rulers often come in a set with protractors so you can measure how far is too far? ;o)

Comment: And of couse, 16thC was a little before plastic or nylon strings!

Comment: Actually, all other things being equal, the breaking pitch of a string doesn't depend on its diameter, only on its makeup and length.

Comment: @ScottWallace under ideal circumstances this is correct, but in reality thicker strings break faster at the bridge if tuned to the same pitch as thinner strings, because the bending angle requires more material flexing.

Comment: @leftaroundabout- yes, I'm aware that there are some secondary effects of thickness on breaking pitch.  Another one: very thin gut strings may break at a lower pitch than thicker ones because they have relatively more broken/polished off fibers.  These effects are pretty minor in my experience, but of course they should be mentioned- thanks.

Comment: Another issue is that gut strings seem to fray a bit, and it doesn't take much fraying to seriously weaken a thing string, but a thicker string can fray a a bit without making much of a difference.  Not speaking from great experience here, as only one of my lutes is strung with gut, and it is the one I play the least.  Only the chanterelle has even broken though (several times).

Answer (score 2):

I know you asked about prior to the 16th century, but...

I've never known a rock band that carried a tuning fork.

Right up to the 1970s you would simply tune to 'whoever sounded about right already' unless there was some external reference like a piano in the building - & whether that was right or not was still questionable.

Comment: I've seen rock bands that didn't even tune...

Comment: The great thing about being tone-deaf is that untuned instruments don't sound bad.

Answer (score 1):

Tuning forks?  References varied a lot locally, but of course the local church organ would be one point of reference.  But organ builders/tuners would be carrying around their own references.

Comment: Tuning forks were not around till the beginning of the next century but one - 1711. Pitch forks, yes, but, hay, that's different.